Help wiring European electric stove in United States
Long story short, I accidently ended up with a new European electric stove in the United States. It's 40 AMP, 240V and 50/60 Hz compatible. Coming off the Circuit breaker I have two hot wires (red/black), Neutral (white) and ground (green). The electric stove has 6 terminals...and two wiring diagrams below for either 2 Hot / 2 Neutral, or 1 Hot / 1 Neutral. As mentioned above, US has a hybrid of 2 hot wires and 1 Neutral. Would appreciate advice on how to wire. Thanks in advance.
Model: Elica Nikolatesla Unplugged blix/a/90 Induction stove integrated hood 90 cm



ask the manufacturer

I have. Unfortunately they are not responsive and cooperating. They simply say, hire an electrician and follow the manual/diagrams.

Usually in these situations you put one hot on L1 and and one hot on N and not use neutral.  Not an expert so this works or goes boom.  The stove does not use 120 and that is the main reason to use the white/neutral wire in NA.  As this is a duplicate to your other question, should delete this one and use the first answer.

One issue is neutral/ground. With European 240 V  mains, one side of the circuit might be neutral, i.e., about ground potential. US split-phase always have neutral in the middle, with 120 VAC either side. If there is any connection between chassis and one of the two power lines, it would not work.

Take the [tour], or go back and actually READ it if you just clicked through and ignored the content, since you supposedly did that already. Edit your closed question to add details that were missing and got it closed. Then it gets reopened. Do NOT just ask the same question again.

Ecnerwal, I'm new to the site and I was having difficulty editing the original post to add a picture of the diagram. I didn't mean a disrespect to the responders. I have read their content, and rewiring with the suggestions. I'm making progress - but still isn't operating. I think DrMoishe Pippik might be on to something. I don't full understand how to determine if there's a connection between the chassis and one of the two power lines?
